# get all excluded dates using moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a last of Date objects that look like this `new Date(2018, 8, 1)`.

I want to feed the list to moment.js and have it give me a list of all the dates that are not included in my array. Is this possible?

If this can be accomplished with some kind of vanilla JS that would be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use vanilla JS with getTime and filter

```
var dates = [
   new Date(2018, 8, 1),
   new Date(2018, 9, 1)
];


console.log([new Date(2018, 8, 1),
  new Date(2018, 9, 1),
  new Date(2018, 10, 1)].filter(function(d) {
    return !dates.some(function(date) {
      return date.getTime() === d.getTime();
    });
  })
);
```